# Angular FormGroup FormArray - submits only one object in array from dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, formarray, angular-formbuilder

I'm trying to create array of objects from dropdown values:

[image]

so the result of selected values from the picture would be `[{person: 'John', country: 'USA'}, {person: 'Pablo', country: 'Mexico'}]` , but form submits only last object.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-populate-values-jq6xya)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you're creating only 1 FormGroup:

```
this.selectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  persons: this.formBuilder.array([
    this.formBuilder.group({
      'person': '',
      'country': ''
    })
  ])
})
```

You should be doing an iteration of `this.parts` to dynamically create them:

```
const persons = <FormArray>this.selectForm.get('persons');

this.parts.forEach((part) => {

  part.persons.forEach((person) => {
    persons.push(this.formBuilder.group({country: null, name: person.name}));
  })
});
```

This will give you two `FormGroup` instances, each having a `country` and a `name` property. This is a more straight-forward way of doing it and it's not as messy as your current solution. You'll have to update the template accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are duplicating formControls instead of creating new ones inside the ngFor loop. Add unique names to form controls for every iteration, it should work.